How does $\lfloor{\frac{y+\Delta-1}{c/l}}\rfloor-\lfloor{\frac{\Delta}{c/l}}\rfloor$ become $\lfloor{\frac{ly-l+(\Delta{}l \bmod c)}{c}}\rfloor$?
In the book "Calendrical Calculations: The Ultimate Edition" by Reingold & Dershowitz, equation 1.85 says
$$
\left\lfloor{\frac{y+\Delta-1}{c/l}}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor{\frac{\Delta}{c/l}}\right\rfloor
= \left\lfloor{\frac{ly - l + (\Delta{}l\textrm{ mod }c)}{c}}\right\rfloor.
$$
This calculates the number of leap years that occur before year $y$, if we want to evenly disperse $l$ leap years over a leap-year cycle of $c$ years, and where the leap years are offset by $\Delta$. Note that $y$, $l$, $c$ and $\Delta$ are all integers.
I am asking for help to understand how the left-hand side can be rewritten into the right hand-side. I have tried two approaches without success. And even if my approaches were successful, they seem too complicated to be the best solution. The book states this equality as if it is trivial; in preceding discussion it has put more effort into explaining steps that seem much simpler to me. So I feel like I'm missing something and over-complicating things.
My first approach was to use the definition of mod provided by the book,
$$x \textrm{ mod } y = x - y\lfloor x/y \rfloor,$$
to write this equality:
$$
\begin{align}
\left\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\right\rfloor
&= \frac{b\lfloor a/b \rfloor}{b}\\
&= \frac{a - a + b\lfloor a/b \rfloor}{b}\\
&= \frac{a - (a - b\lfloor a/b \rfloor)}{b}\\
&= \frac{a - (a\textrm{ mod } b)}{b}.\\
\end{align}
$$
This allows me to write
$$
\begin{align}
\left\lfloor{\frac{y+\Delta-1}{c/l}}\right\rfloor
&= \left\lfloor{\frac{ly+\Delta{}l-l}{c}}\right\rfloor\\
&= \frac{ly+\Delta{}l-l - (ly+\Delta{}l-l)\textrm{ mod }c}{c}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\left\lfloor{\frac{\Delta}{c/l}}\right\rfloor
= \left\lfloor{\frac{\Delta{}l}{c}}\right\rfloor
= \frac{\Delta{}l - \Delta{}l\textrm{ mod } c}{c}
$$
giving me
$$
\begin{align}
& \left\lfloor{\frac{y+\Delta-1}{c/l}}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor{\frac{\Delta}{c/l}}\right\rfloor\\
=& \frac{ly+\Delta{}l-l - (ly+\Delta{}l-l)\textrm{ mod }c}{c} - 
\frac{\Delta{}l - \Delta{}l\textrm{ mod } c}{c}\\
=& \frac{ly+\Delta{}l-l - (ly+\Delta{}l-l)\textrm{ mod }c - 
\Delta{}l + \Delta{}l\textrm{ mod } c}{c}\\
=& \frac{ly - l - (ly+\Delta{}l-l)\textrm{ mod }c + \Delta{}l\textrm{ mod } c}{c}\\\end{align}.
$$
But here's where I'm stuck. Perhaps I need to get the $ly - l$ part out of the mod dividend but I don't see how I could do that, plus that would leave me with two $\Delta{}l$ terms that seem to cancel out? The right-hand side of the book's equation has a floor function around the entire right hand side, so perhaps that can be employed somehow to simplify the expression.
My second approach was to define
$$
a = \lfloor a \rfloor + \{a\}
$$
where $\{a\}$ is the fractional part of $a$. Then
$$
a + b
= \lfloor a \rfloor + \{a\} + \lfloor b \rfloor + \{b\}
= \lfloor a \rfloor + \lfloor b \rfloor + \{a\} + \{b\}
$$
and
$$
\lfloor a+b \rfloor
= \lfloor a \rfloor + \lfloor b \rfloor + \lfloor \{a\} + \{b\} \rfloor.
$$
If I could somehow extract an integer part and a fractional part out of the expression I ended up with in my first approach, perhaps I could use this pattern to reverse back to a floor expression that matches the book's right-hand side. But again, I feel like out on too deep water considering how casually the books states the equivalence.

The solution is somewhat simpler that what you've tried since it only really needs to handle $\Delta l$ in terms of it being an integral multiple of $c$ plus a remainder. First, as you've done, simplify the LHS of your original equation by multiplying the numerators and denominators of both fractions inside the floor functions by $l$ to get
$$\left\lfloor{\frac{y + \Delta - 1}{c/l}}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor{\frac{\Delta}{c/l}}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor{\frac{ly - l + \Delta l}{c}}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor{\frac{\Delta l}{c}}\right\rfloor$$
Using the division theorem, and with $c$ being a positive integer, there exists unique integers $q$ and $r$ where
$$\Delta l = qc + r, \;\; 0 \le r \le c - 1$$
Note that $r = (\Delta l\bmod c)$, were $\bmod$ refers to the modulo operation, so the above equation becomes
$$\Delta l = qc + (\Delta l\bmod c)$$
Substitute this into the RHS of the first equation, along with using the floor function equivalence that for any integer $n$ we have $\lfloor n + x\rfloor = n + \lfloor x\rfloor$, and also that $0 \le \Delta l\bmod c \le c - 1 \;\to\; 0 \le \frac{\Delta l\bmod c}{c} \lt 1 \;\to\; \left\lfloor\frac{\Delta l\bmod c}{c}\right\rfloor = 0$, to get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left\lfloor{\frac{ly - l + \color{blue}{\Delta l}}{c}}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor{\frac{\color{blue}{\Delta l}}{c}}\right\rfloor & = \left\lfloor{\frac{ly - l + \color{blue}{qc + (\Delta l\bmod c)}}{c}}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor{\frac{\color{blue}{qc + (\Delta l\bmod c)}}{c}}\right\rfloor \\
& = \left\lfloor{\frac{qc}{c} + \frac{ly - l + (\Delta l\bmod c)}{c}}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor{\frac{qc}{c} + \frac{\Delta l\bmod c}{c}}\right\rfloor \\
& = \left\lfloor{q + \frac{ly - l + (\Delta l\bmod c)}{c}}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor{q + \frac{\Delta l\bmod c}{c}}\right\rfloor \\
& = q + \left\lfloor{\frac{ly - l + (\Delta l\bmod c)}{c}}\right\rfloor - q - \left\lfloor{\frac{\Delta l\bmod c}{c}}\right\rfloor \\
& = \left\lfloor{\frac{ly - l + (\Delta l\bmod c)}{c}}\right\rfloor
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
This matches the RHS of your original equation, showing the equality holds.

More generally, for any integers $a$ and $b$ (with $a = ly - l$ and $b = \Delta l$ for this particular problem), we have
$$\left\lfloor\frac{a + b}{c}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{b}{c}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{a + (b\bmod c)}{c}\right\rfloor$$

I'm confused about the last step where you combine the two terms into a single floor function. Is there an equivalence relation that lets us do that?

@flodin If you're referring to the last step of my set of equations, i.e., going from $q + \left\lfloor{\frac{ly - l + (\Delta l\bmod c)}{c}}\right\rfloor - q - \left\lfloor{\frac{\Delta l\bmod c}{c}}\right\rfloor$ to $\left\lfloor{\frac{ly - l + (\Delta l\bmod c)}{c}}\right\rfloor$, note the $q$ and $-q$ terms cancel, plus as I explained just above that, we have $\left\lfloor\frac{\Delta l\bmod c}{c}\right\rfloor = 0$. Thus, the only term left is that one in my last line. If you're referring to my generalization, it's just what I did with your case, in a more general setting.
